# vsto Range.Find on empty single cell selection returns range outside of the cell

Tags: c#, excel, com, range, vsto

In my VSTO add-in project if I select a single empty cell, like F11, and run find on that range for any value, it seems to search the entire sheet and returns the range A1:E10 when I expect it to return null. Below is an image of the cell I have selected.

[image]

I am accessing this range through the selection, which when I inspect while debugging, has a column of 6 and row of 11, which is what I selected. When I try to find anything in this range I expect I should get a null but instead I get the value of E10, which makes no sense.

Here is my c# code the first part gets a selection and iterates through the 
ranges areas, in the case of a single selection there is only 1 area.

The values of val1 and val2 at the end are both 3197077000 even though F11 is the only cell selected.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            Excel.Range selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

            if (null != selection)
            {
                var sheet = selection.Worksheet;
                var book = (Excel.Workbook)sheet.Parent;

                var areasCount = selection.Areas.Count;

                for (int i = 1; i <= areasCount; i++)
                {
                    var area = selection.Areas[i];

                    var test = area.Value;
                    var testCount = area.Count;
                    var testRow = area.Row;
                    var testCol = area.Column;

                    Excel.Range lastCellInLastRow = area.Find(
                    "*",
                    Type.Missing,
                    XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                    XlLookAt.xlPart,
                    XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                    XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                    false,
                    Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing);

                    Excel.Range lastCellInLastCol = area.Find(
                        "*",
                        Type.Missing,
                        XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                        XlLookAt.xlPart,
                        XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                        XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                        false,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing);

                    var val1 = lastCellInLastCol.Value;
                    var val2 = lastCellInLastRow.Value;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do the same thing in VBA I get a null when running find on F11 as expected

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SelectionTest()
    Dim selection As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim UsedRange As Variant
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set selection = Application.selection

    Dim area As Range

    Debug.Print "selection columns " & selection.Columns.Count

    Dim finalRng As Range
    Dim finalArr As Variant

    For Each area In selection.Areas
        Debug.Print "single rng columns " & area.Columns.Count
        Set lastCell = area.Find(What:="*", After:=area.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        Set lastCell = area.Find(What:="*", After:=area.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        Debug.Print lastCell

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You drop a lot of code into your question; a good deal of it refers to libraries most of us won't have or won't know what they are. Could you please create a [mcve] that clearly reflects the problem situation - using only standard VSTO - so that we can investigate efficiently?

Comment: @CindyMeister updated to use standard VSTO libraries in a smaller example.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Interop / Range.Find can be unreliable. Use Interop as little as you possibly can.

Longer answer: One of the unreliable things I've noticed in practice about `Range.Find` is that it seems to have a memory of what was last searched for before. That may or may not be the issue here, but if I were you I wouldn't bother trying to figure it out, because you can solve your problem as follows:

- Read your entire range into memory as a two dimensional array
- Cast the array elements to strings
- Use robust `C#` regex libraries and nested for loops to search through the array

A bit more work, but worth it to get away from the unreliable foundation that is Interop. Here's a little code to get you started, around reading ranges:

```
public string[,] ReadValues(Range range)
{
    return ConvertToStringArray2D(GetArray(range, () => range.Value2));
}

private string[,] ConvertToStringArray2D(Array values)
{
    string[,] retArray = new string[values.GetLength(0), values.GetLength(1)];

    // loop through the 2-D System.Array and populate the 1-D String Array
    for (int row = 1; row <= values.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= values.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            if (values.GetValue(row, col) == null)
            {
                retArray[row - 1, col - 1] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                retArray[row - 1, col - 1] = values.GetValue(row, col).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return retArray;
}

private Array OneBasedSingletonArray2D()
{
    return Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), new int[] { 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1 });
}       

private Array GetArray(Range range, Func<object> dataProducer)
{
    if (range.Cells.Count == 0)
    {
        return Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), 0, 0);
    }
    if (range.Cells.Count == 1)
    {
        //Creating a 1-based array to fit with Excel's 1-based indexing
        Array retArray = OneBasedSingletonArray2D();
        retArray.SetValue(dataProducer.Invoke(), 1, 1);
        return retArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return (Array)dataProducer.Invoke();
    }
}
```